# I need a psychologist ,i want to write him online

Tags: mental-health, psychiatrist-psychiatry, psychologist-psychology

i want to send a problem i have and to take an answer.I went to a psychologist recently but the main key of the situation was he couldnt understand my situation.I would like to write to a psychologist like an email.The reason is ,if i visit i would forget detail,i would upset my mind will not work properly.I have searched the internet but maybe i couldnt find something like that.I find only chat conversations and that i dont wanted to.Is there something to write my whole problem and after he/she will read it and he/she will obtain an aspect of view?(I want to send it only to him i dont want to be my problem public).What you have to suggested me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can not recommend an online psychologist for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your psychologist and ask for such option if you can get the e-mail, because you would like to explain your situation in writing.

If they don't have, you can explain your situation on the paper either handwriting or on the computer and print it before going to the appointment.

Especially when it's a private psychologist, they'll love to read what you've written to understand better your situation. In public clinic usually they've tight timeframes. But it may all depend on the specific psychologist and their approach, some of them would want to assess your situation by the direct approach.

Even when they wouldn't want to read it, it's worth to print such document just for your self (even if it's just [a mind map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map)), so you won't forget any details what you wanted to share.

If you looking just for online psychologist, I'm sure you can write to them as you like, whether via e-mail, chat or web forms. Search online for some, then send the message explaining your situation and find the most suitable for you who can understand your problems and can help you.

Comment: thans,but i would like to something that i cant take online help.It would better for me.Is there a site that can help me with this?

Comment: You prefer to find an online psychologist?

Comment: yes.I dont want to chat.I want first to write him my problem.It would take me to write my problem i think 30 minutes and after to read it at least 1 hour so i want  to send it to him.Its and theme from money it takes a lot.In the internet i think there are people who can help you and give you much help and they dont see your pocket.I think you know what i mean

Comment: @e.p You need to find a private psychologist that does that. On this site we cannot recommend you any psychologist. Google it and find the email to local psychologist, send him the e-mail explaining briefly the situation and wait for the response if he's happy to cooperate in this way.